# Stream data as json object in pig

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have a script that takes complex json objects (one per line) in input and outputs in a hadoc format. I would like to use pig to stream some data through this script using STREAM. How can I force pig to send the data to streaming in json format? I am looking for something like

```
C = stream A through `stream.py` USING JsonStorage()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be no such implementation yet in pig. The best alternative might be to use the [ToJson UDF](https://github.com/rjurney/pig-to-json) which outputs a json string, then in the streaming function load the string as a json object, for instance, using python's json.loads(inputstring).